# nothing happens when i execute the code. Got my methods right?

Tags: java, methods

I have a  code, and im supposed to return the rectangles area and perimeter on a JPanel. But when i execute nothing happens at all. Im suspecting an error somewhere in my methods cus i belive the rest is ok. Ill appricate all help. 
Im just gonna show you my code in  the JPanel.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Rektanglar extends JPanel {

    Rektanglar r1 = new Rektanglar ();

    @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {    
       super.paintComponent (g);
       g.drawString ("Rektanglar",10,20);
       this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
       g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       g.fillRect(r1.getX(),r1.getY(), r1.getWidth(), r1.getHeight());
    }

    public int Y; 
    public int X; 
    public int width; 
    public int height; 
    public int Perimeter; 
    public int Area; 

    Rektanglar (){ 
        width = 10; 
        height = 10; 
        X = 0; 
        Y = 0;        
    }     

    public void Rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public void setX(int X ){ 
        this.X = X;
    }

    public int getX(int X){
        return X;
    }

    public void setY(int Y){
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    public int getY( int Y){
        return Y;
    }

    public int getWidth( int width){
        return width;
    } 

    public int getHeight(int height){
        return height;
    }

    public int getPerimeter(){
        return (width + width + height + height );
    }

    public int getArea(){
        return (height * width);}
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `void` from `public void Rectangle(...)`

Comment: Also, your class' name is 'Rektanglar', not 'Rectangle'

Comment: Please go get a Java book first...

Comment: when i do that i get an error that return type is required :/ @whowantsakookie

Comment: It sounds like you don't know a lot about constructors. Maybe [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) will help.

Comment: @m0skito i have a java book, and why is it that i have to be an expert in order to ask questions in here? Books dont always help you see errors and understand.

Comment: This is **absolute basic Java**. If you don't know this, then yes, you should not be asking here.

Comment: ok thanks for ruining my selfasteem @whowantsakookie

Comment: I'm not. You should just learn more before asking a simple question.

Comment: @Patricia6946 The important thing to realize here is that first studying Java on one's own time helps communicating *about* java. You can then, enabled with that knowledge, ask questions with important details without running into basic errors.

Answer (score 4):

If you ever actually try to construct an instance of `Rektanglar`, you'll get a stack overflow due to this:

```
public class Rektanglar extends JPanel {
   Rektanglar r1 = new Rektanglar ();
   ...
}
```

That code says that in order to create one instance, you need to create another instance... which will create yet another instance, etc.

It's not at all clear why you've got `r1` at all, but I strongly suggest you get rid of it...

I also suspect this:

```
public void Rectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
```

... is meant to be a constructor, in which case you'd have to write it as:

```
public Rektanglar(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
```

Note that the name has to match the name of the class *and* you don't specify a return type.

Additionally, I'd suggest that:

- You make all fields private
- You compute the perimeter and area from the width and height, rather than keeping them as fields
- You follow Java naming conventions for your variables (so `x` and `y` instead of `X` and `Y`).

Comment: thanks a lot. That was very well described!!!

Comment: well actually i was using r1 because im supposed to have two rectangles so i wanted to name the other one r2 but i removed it just in order to make this wórk first with one. I felt easier that way :)

Comment: @Patricia6946: If you want two instances, create two instances - but you don't want *every* instance containing another instance. You haven't shown what's *calling* any of this code - but that's probably where you want to create the two instances.

Comment: Jon, i don't think she realizes what she is actually doing :)

Comment: dont worry, ill never ask in here cus i really didnt expect people to be rude when someone is asking for help. @jnardiello

Comment: @Patricia6946: While I don't believe rudeness is called for, your question is also not nearly as clear as it could be. I suspect that if you put more effort into researching it, you may have found your answer for yourself. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - and remember that Stack Overflow really *isn't* a good place to learn a language from scratch. It's good for very specific problems, including beginner problems, but it's definitely no substitute for a good book and hard work.

Comment: Instead of telling YOU that i dont know what im doing he could have talked to my directly and not refer to me in 3rd person. And also i didnt know that it wasnt allowed to ask questions here if you are new in java. Next time its better to say : Im sorry but stack overflow is not used for helping out with basic java problems. Difficult? if yes, then its rude the way some answered here. Thanks anyway @JonSkeet

Comment: @Patricia6946 The question isn't "basic". Many things are basic in the language but have complex roots in mathematics and logic. However, trivial issues due to poor understanding of Java can't reasonable be solved by a "give me a fish" style of question. It's "give me a fish" vs "teach me to fish". You're doing the former here.

Comment: @Patricia6946 Sorry, i really didn't mean to sound rude. It's just that your code shows very poor efforts in actually "understanding" and "learning" Java. By saying this i'm not insulting nor i want you to get offended, don't take this personally. It's just a general consideration which i hope will help you doing better in future :)

Comment: how can i resign from this page? @JonSkeet

Comment: @Patricia6946: I'm not sure what you mean. You can't delete this question now it has an answer with upvotes... but you could potentially improve it... or just move on with your life, and take more care asking your next question.

Comment: sorry i meant i want to delete my acccount @jon skeet